# Amazon AWS CPP SDK Get S3 Bucket Download Progress

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-web-services

On Linux I am using the AWS CPP SDK to download a 23 MB file from an S3 Bucket with the following code. It works great but I want to get the download progress as well. I cannot find any examples on Google. I think I need to set the "SetDataReceivedEventHandler) callback. Can anyone tell me what that function should look like / how I can implement it and register it? Thanks.

```
    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest;
    getObjectRequest.SetBucket(bucket.c_str());
    getObjectRequest.SetKey(keyName.c_str());
    getObjectRequest.SetResponseStreamFactory([&destination](){
     return Aws::New<Aws::FStream>(
     "s3file", destination, std::ios_base::out); });

    // getObjectRequest.SetDataReceivedEventHandler() <--- How do I use this?

    GetObjectOutcome getObjectOutcome = SessionClient->GetObject(getObjectRequest);
    if(getObjectOutcome.IsSuccess())
    {
        std::cout << "<AWS DOWNLOAD> Get FW success!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "<AWS DOWNLOAD> Get FW failed: " << getObjectOutcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C? This definitely isn't valid C code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [TransferManager](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-transfer/include/aws/transfer/TransferManager.h) ? It has download [progress callbacks](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_transfer_1_1_transfer_manager.html#a9be29960daca5ea1cfbc199ecb43a128).
[Full doc link](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_transfer_1_1_transfer_manager.html)